# how to grep between 2 patterns - second occurence BASH

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I need to extract a section of file between two patterns,
From match the first pattern until match second pattern twice

I have the next file

```
FileSet {
  Name = "FileseT-XXXXX"
   Include {
    Options {
      signature = MD5
     }
       File = /etc
       File = /usr/sbin
       File = /root
       File = /srv/
}
}

#SECOND FILESET
FileSet {
  Name = "FileseT-XXXXX2"
  Include {
    Options {
      signature = MD5
    }
       File = /srv/
}
```

}

I want to grep based on 'Name = "FileseT-XXXXX"' to the second "}" to obtain  Files in section.

I want to obtain the first four "File"

```
    File = /etc
    File = /usr/sbin
    File = /root
    File = /srv/
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to get as complicated as you describe just to print the `File =` lines in the target block. All you need is:

```
$ awk '/Name = /{f=/"FileseT-XXXXX"/} f && /File =/' file
       File = /etc
       File = /usr/sbin
       File = /root
       File = /srv/
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Comment: Thanks for the remark @EdMorton. Your solution is more concise and so simple.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would narrow down the dataset by matching data between `"FileseT-XXXXX"` and `FileSet`. Then I would extract the desired `File` parts.

This should do the trick to extract only the files:

```
pattern='XXXXX'

awk -v n="\"FileseT-$pattern\"" '$0 ~ n {flag=1; next} /FileSet/{flag=0} flag' your_data_file | awk '/File = / {print $0}'
```

You can save your pattern into a shell variable. Note that you can use shell variables in awk with the `-v` flag. This way you can easily change the desired pattern in your script. Then using ***awk*** pattern matching you can extract the lines between the `"FileseT-XXXXX"` and the first occurence of `FileSet` exluding them from the output. Then piping (`|`) the results to another ***awk*** call, where we extract only the desired lines.

***EDIT***:

To extract the lines between the `"FileseT-XXXXX"` and the second occurrence of `}`:

```
awk -v n="\"FileseT-$n\"" '$0 ~ n {flag=1; next} /}/ && ++c == 2 {flag=0} flag' your_data_file
```

Comment: Thats work fine, One question, it is possible to extract lines between the "FileseT-XXXXX" and the second occurrence of  ' } '  ? Thanks :D